# Get variable in sql statment and use in php

Tags: php, mysql

The function below generates a table like the image below.

[image]

The location_id is being accessed but I would like to use this ID again at the bottom of the table in a link. See the LOCATION_ID at the bottom of the function.

Im not sure how to do this.

```
function countAppointment2() {

  require 'config.php';

  $data = array();
  $date_list= array();
  $sql_date_list ="SELECT start_date from appointment GROUP BY start_date";
  $result_date_list = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_date_list); 
  $sql_loc_list = "SELECT `name` FROM `location` GROUP BY `name`";
  $result_loc_list = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_loc_list); 
  $k=0;
  while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_loc_list)){
      $data +=[$row['name']=>array()];
      if($k==0){
          while($row2 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_date_list)){
              array_push($date_list,$row2['start_date']);
              $data[$row['name']]+=[$row2['start_date']=>0];
          }
          $k++;
      }else{
          foreach($date_list as $date){
              $data[$row['name']]+=[$date=>0];
          }
      }
  }
  
  $sql_getdata = "SELECT t2.name as loc_name, t1.start_date,t1.location_id, COUNT(t1.location_id) AS count FROM appointment t1 JOIN location t2 ON t1.location_id = t2.id GROUP BY t1.location_id,t1.start_date"; 
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_getdata); 
  while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $data[$row['loc_name']][$row['start_date']]=$row['count'];         
  }
  $table="<table class='table table-bordered'>";
  $table.="<thead><tr>";
  $table.="<th>Dealership Location</th>";
  foreach ($date_list as $date) {
    $edate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date));
      $table.="<th>".$edate."</th>";
  }
  $table.="</tr></thead>";
  foreach ($data as $key=>$date) {
      $table.="<tbody><tr>";
      $table.="<td>".$key."</td>";
          foreach($date as $key2=>$count){
              $table.="<td><a href=appointments-by-day?id=".$LOCATION_ID.">".$count."</a></td>";
          }
      $table.="</tr>";
  }
  
  $table.="</tbody></table>";
  echo $table;
}
```

Comment: why didn#t you use the dynamic function, it would be easier to process

Comment: change `$dat<snip>ate']]=$row['count'];` to `$dat<snip>ate']]=['count'=>$row['count'], 'location_id' =>$row['location_id']];` then use `$count['count']`, and `$count['location_id']` in the loop when outputting the link.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Like this? `$data[$row['loc_name']][$row['start_date']]=$row['count'=>$row['count'], 'location_id' =>$row['location_id']];`

Comment: yep, see answer

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Change

`$data[$row['loc_name']][$row['start_date']]=$row['count'];`

to

```
$data[$row['loc_name']][$row['start_date']] = [
   'count' => $row['count'], 
   'location_id' => $row['location_id']
];
```

Then replace the code in the loop to:

```
$table.="<td><a href=appointments-by-day?id=".$count['location_id'].">".$count['count']."</a></td>";
```

Essentially changing it from a single value to an array.

Comment: The only issue with this is that if the row count is 0, nothing is displayed.

Comment: nowhere in your code would it do that, hows it outputting 0 in the table if 0 is not set by the $row['count']?

Comment: the table cell is now blank. And I get this error refering to the $table. line - AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in

Comment: reread my answer, you have not changed the code if `$count` is still an int, if you want the location_id when there are no rows then your need to do a separate query

Comment: I have put your code in my function. Before if the count was 0, a 0 would be displayed in the cell. Now, the cell is blank. I have added an if statement to fix this `if (!isset($count['count'])){               $table.="<td>0</td>";             }             else {             $table.="<td><a href=appointments-by-day?id=".$count['start_date'].">".$count['count']."</a></td>";             }`